# Determining data type in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

How it is possible to set attributes when we import data from a CSV file? I have set "y" as label but I can not run the process because Input Example set has no attributes. 
Is there anyone who can help me to solve it?

Comment: Did you try the wizard? It usually does a good job of getting the initial set up done.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the roles and types of the attributes in *data set meta data information* in the read csv parameters.
But as mentioned before i would recommend running the import wizard!

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of solving this problem is using Set Role operator on a pre-loaded dataset from CSV.